# Add your Stage in a ScrollWindow ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I'm gonna try explaining my situation with images, to make sure that everyone will understand what i want to succeed.

First of all i have 3 files:

**GenImage.fla** which is linked to class **GeneralImage.as**
and it only contains the following picture (I tried to make the image Movie Clip but again it's not working):

[Pic1](http://s23.postimg.org/xswcw57fv/Adobe_Flash_Player_17_2015_07_02_at_18_29_22.png)

and a file named **ScrollUI.as** which contains the class **ScrollUI**.

What i want to succeed is from my GeneralImage class to create a ScrollUi item, pass the stage, and there create a ScrollPane which makes the picture look like this:

[Pic2](http://s24.postimg.org/qlupnxys5/Adobe_Flash_Player_17_2015_07_02_at_18_31_03.png)

The center part of the second image is the ScrollPane Component, which i need to make it Scrollable through the whole image. I managed to get it in my screen but i can't put the Stage in it and make it scrollable.

These are my codes :

**GeneralImage.as**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import ScrollUI;


    public class GeneralImage extends MovieClip
    {

        public function GeneralImage()
        {
            var k = new ScrollUI();
            k.ScrollConstructor(this);

        }

    }

}
```

**ScrollUI.as**

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.containers.ScrollPane; 
    import fl.events.ScrollEvent;
    import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy; 

    public class ScrollUI extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _mainStage:Stage;
        var aBox:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
        var aSp:ScrollPane = new ScrollPane();

        public function ScrollUI()
        {
        }

        function ScrollConstructor(stage:Object):void
        {
            _mainStage = (stage as MovieClip).stage;
            aBox == stage as MovieClip;
            aSp.source == aBox ;
            _mainStage.addChild(aBox);
            aSp.setSize(300,300);
            aSp.move(150, 75); 
            aSp.scrollDrag = true;
            aSp.horizontalScrollPolicy=ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            _mainStage.addChild(aSp);

        }
    }

}
```

So what i want it to set the Source of the Scroll Pane ( which is named aSp ) to be the _mainStage which is the stage i get from GeneralImage

Comment: You can't set the stage of your swf as the scroll panes content (as it's a parent/grandparent of your scroll pane).  Why can't you make the image a movieClip in Flash?  What is the current result of your code?

Comment: My current result with this code is the picture in background and the scroll window in the centre. I can make it movie clip , basically I already tried it but it brings out the same result

Comment: I already have the basic stage passed into the subclass I just need to put it inside the scroll

Comment: Your `ScrollUI` class extends MovieClip, don't you're never adding it to the display, you seem to be just trying to add the scroll pane directly to the stage.  This seems rather odd.   Is `GeneralImage.as` your document class?

Comment: Yes that's my 'main' class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues is likely these two lines:

```
 aBox == stage as MovieClip;
 aSp.source == aBox ;
```

You're doing a comparison by using two `==`, which effectively does nothing in your case.  Use a single `=` to assign a value.

This is how I would suggest you approach this:

In the FlashPro library, find your image asset (I'm going to assume you have it wrapped in a MovieClip), right-click (or command click) and go to it's properties.  Check the "*export for actionscript*" box, and give it a meaningful class name (for my example, I'll assume you called it **MyImage**)

Then you could do the following:

**ScrollUI Class**

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import fl.containers.ScrollPane; 
    import fl.events.ScrollEvent;
    import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy; 

    public class ScrollUI extends Sprite
    {
        //just declare the variables here, don't assign them new values
        private var aBox:MovieClip; 
        private var aSp:ScrollPane;

        public function ScrollUI()
        {
            //use the actual constructor...

            aSp = new ScrollPane(); //instantiate a new scroll pane
            addChild(aSp); //add the scroll pane to the display

            aBox = new MyImage(); //instantiate an new MyImage from the library
            //set the scroll pane properties
            aSp.source = aBox; //you had two = signs here before, which doesn't actually assign anything it compares
            aSp.setSize(300,300);
            aSp.move(150, 75); 
            aSp.scrollDrag = true;
            aSp.horizontalScrollPolicy=ScrollPolicy.OFF;

        }
    }

}
```

**Document Class**

```
package  {

    import ScrollUI;


    public class GeneralImage extends MovieClip
    {

        public function GeneralImage()
        {
            var k:ScrollUI = new ScrollUI(); //create a new instance of the ScrollUI class
            addChild(k); //add the scrollUI object to the display;

            //OR, you just do this:
            //addChild(new ScrollUI());
        }

    }

}
```

You could also just set the `.source` property of the scroll pane to the physical path of your image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i posted the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Thanks Batman for his help, I changes some things into my code and the program is working.

First of all as Batman said , In my **GenImage.fla** i made the logo a MovieClip and i named it "wholemap"

Here are my codes :

**GeneralImage.as**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import ScrollUI;

    public class GeneralImage extends MovieClip
    {
//as Batman indicated, I should have used the ScrollUI constructor, but 
//except for the Stage, i also send the wholemap that is in my GenImage.fla
//<< this.getChildByName("wholemap") as MovieClip) >>
        public function GeneralImage()
        {
            var k = new ScrollUI(this, this.getChildByName("wholemap") as MovieClip); 
        }
    }

}
```

**ScrollUI.as**

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.containers.ScrollPane; 
    import fl.events.ScrollEvent;
    import fl.controls.ScrollPolicy; 

    public class ScrollUI extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _mainStage:Stage;
        var aBox:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
    //So our constructor gets 2 items, a Stage, and a MovieClip
        public function ScrollUI(stage:Object, pic:MovieClip)
        {
    //We set the Stage at the variable _mainStage with that way:
            _mainStage = (stage as MovieClip).stage;
    //We set the Image that we will take at our clip variable :
            var clip:MovieClip = pic;
    //And we send the Movieclip (clip) in our ScrollConstructor function
            ScrollConstructor(clip);
        }

        function ScrollConstructor(Clip:MovieClip):void
        {
            var aSp:ScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            aBox = Clip;
            _mainStage.addChild(aBox);
            aSp.source = aBox ;
            aSp.setSize(300,300);
            aSp.move(150, 75); 
            aSp.scrollDrag = true;
            aSp.horizontalScrollPolicy=ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            aSp.verticalScrollPolicy=ScrollPolicy.OFF;
            _mainStage.addChild(aSp);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for your assistance, I hope if someone else come across with this problem to be able to solve it with this Answer